Astro dev start with podman: error getting image label
I'm trying to follow the astronomer airflow tutorial ebook using podman, and I hit an error that apparently no else on the internet has.
When I run astro dev start, podman completes all the steps in the dockerfile, but then it throws the following error:
error getting image label

And fails entirely. Airflow never starts locally.
Podman works, I've been using it for a while in a separate project without issues. I also inspected the image in the dockerfile and podman finds it.
I can't find ANYTHING related to this error anywhere, so I'm very confused.

did you check and follow the steps for Podman?
Astro CLI Podman

Yes, I did. I don't even have docker installed, so its using podman without a doubt.
